# Permission problems running WordPress on Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos, file-permissions, vesta

I am using the VestaCP with Ngnix & Centos OS. And I was unable to install the plugins through the WordPress dashboard. It is giving error like;

> Installation failed: Could not create directory.

And my directories permission is set to 755 and files to 644. But when I set the permission of directories and files to 777, then I can install plugins and run it. But I know that 777 is security threat.

Therefore any helps

Comment: You should also change the owner of the WordPress files:

`chown -R user:user /home/user/web/yourdomain.tld/public_html`

Comment: @RoseHosting, I set the directories to 755 and files to 644, then using the command you given ie ( chown -R root:root /home/admin/web/coupon.mn/public_html ) --- still cannot installed the plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I put the following code and it works like a charm. chown -R admin:admin /home/user/web/yourdomain.tld/public_html

Answer (score 0):

The method that worked for me was replacing user with the actual username on the server.

In my case, I did  `chown -R learners:learners /home/learners/public_html/wp-content`

and just like magic, the problem was solved